# create page programmatically for a test user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can I create via api pages for a test users?

This is what I did: 
Given my app, I got the user's token from app dashboard test users and I tried to use it in the graph explorer (POST /user_id/accounts).

I've the error "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action".
These are the permission the app has been granted for: manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions

Do I miss some permission or it is not possible?

Luca

Comment: not sure if you are dealing with marketing api, but there is an endpoint you can leverage to create a page: POST {business_id}/pages. This one requires business_management permission

Answer (score 1):

[Edited following Simon's advice and the response below:]

I've been looking into this all day and it seems the answer is a solid, "Nope."

According to the [developer documentation on creating pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating), the {user_id}/accounts endpoint only supports Reading, not Creating, Updating, or Deleting.

Although apparently if you apply for [Standard API access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access), you can receive permissions to create pages. (Only available if your app is generating ad revenue.)

Comment: Also if your answer isn't correct, it's been useful for finding the solution. If you read the the documentation it seems that it is possible creating pages posting on /{user_id}/accounts, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Googling, reading and trying, I figure out that we can create a page via api.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Creating 
> Applications with Standard API Access can create Pages through the API using the following paths: /{user_id}/accounts

So the answer to my question is yes, if your application has the Standard API Access, no matter if you are dealing with test users or not. Note that teh call is slow (about 5 sec.)

That's it.